# What does '' as <alias> do?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a query which has `'' as <alias>` multiple times, for example:

```
SELECT -- ...
'' as first_name,
'' as last_name, 
'' as email_address
-- ...
```

This seems to only return columns with empty values.

Are there any other side effects of this query?

The query is old and I believe there are clients expecting these fields (empty or not).

Does this cause any overhead I would be better off handling in Java?
Is there are better way to return empty columns without this unintuitive clause?

Comment: Literally selects empty values back with Header Information.

Comment: It's rather intuitive to anybody who has been working with SQL for enough time... It's a common thing to do in unions, where only some of the union clauses return real data in those columns. It's also common to do in cases where you have several alternative queries that should all return the same result set structure.

Comment: Seriously, this is well documented in every SQL reference. Which references did you use that failed to answer that?

Comment: @LewBloch do you mind pointing me in the right direction? I would still like to read more about this.

Comment: Literally any SQL reference. IBM, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, it's a placeholder to make the column appear in the output.  It would have no other effect on the query.

The only overhead of note this would cause would be the cost of transferring the extra column data over the network to your Java process.  But as they're empty strings, unless you're talking 100M rows, it's going to be negligible.

If you want confirmation that it's not causing DB overhead, use the [MySQL EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) feature to detail the costs of the query.